# Performing an SQL cast in Slick

Tags: sql, scala, slick

Using Slick, I know I can map an sql function to a scala value like this:

```
val toChar = SimpleFunction.binary[Date, String, String]("TO_CHAR")
```

and call it like this:

```
toChar.apply(dateColumn, "yyyy-MM-dd")
```

Is there a way to map the `CAST` function? It has a different form: `CAST(dateColumn AS CHAR)`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it like this:

```
SimpleExpression.unary[Date, String] { (date, qb) =>
      qb.sqlBuilder += "CAST( "
      qb.expr(date)
      qb.sqlBuilder += " AS CHAR)"
    }
```

Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 6):

There is already `someString.asColumnOf[Int]`. And there is `SimpleExpression` for mapping it yourself. See the "user defined" manual section. There is a usage example in `JdbcScalarFunctionTest` in our test suite.